# Подсчет количества слов в тексте(с исправленным кодом и дополнениями К уже заданному вопросу "Подсчет количества слов в тексте")

Tags: python-3.x, строки, re

Моё изменённое решение такое:
Разбиваем по словам - убираем всё лишнее. В цикле проверяем, не запрещённое ли слово и увеличиваем счетчик - ещё добавил запрещённые слова перевёл в capitalize() и пробел и поместил в множество

Вот получил такую подсказку:направление указал Эникейщик
А ведь слово может начинаться и с большой буквы, и, например, "and" и "And" — разные слова.

```
import codewars_test as test

import re

except_word = {"a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in", "as",
               "A", "The", "On", "At", "Of", "Upon", "In", "As", ""
               }


def word_count(s):
    all_word = re.sub(r'([^A-Za-z]+)', r' ', s).split(' ')
    cnt = 0
    for word in all_word:
        if word in except_word:
            continue
        else:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there"), 2)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there and a hi"), 4)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("I'd like to say goodbye"), 6)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("Slow-moving user6463 has been here"), 6)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("%^&abc!@# wer45tre"), 3)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("abc123abc123abc"), 3)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("Really2374239847 long ^&#$&(*@# sequence"), 3)

    long_text = r"""
            I’d been using my sphere as a stool. I traced counterclockwise circles on it with my fingertips and it shrank until I could palm it. My bolt had shifted while I’d been sitting. I pulled it up and yanked the pleats straight as I careered around tables, chairs, globes, and slow-moving fraas. I passed under a stone arch into the Scriptorium. The place smelled richly of ink. Maybe it was because an ancient fraa and his two fids were copying out books there. But I wondered how long it would take to stop smelling that way if no one ever used it at all; a lot of ink had been spent there, and the wet smell of it must be deep into everything.
            """

    test.assert_equals(word_count(long_text), 112)
```

Теперь моя функция выдаёт правильные ответы на базовые тесты

Вот такой рандомный тест с сервера не проходит как и все остальные рандомные тесты
всегда получается на 1-о слово больше

```
st = """R;!GV9sZrD 5x=jncajkU Z#0qd' rR"8oeAy:; IO$"EhYI), NG("Cy28 +ix>i kq&rV/ ',Sl[PL~ Ae/[< \-T<:/ D-$W9p5,Qh yF)DFS XFR@x{8[. L+(]M-cW J+i~E =g5B"1rGoM @c*ByGCt _2amHl =Y8f*E) P_F}01o t}1q!+A@| B3"S;; dP..'U >FqS>4D(S %rf/# =jB$+F<M G$:|K"rJn m92Fkv I^xuZ )s@~R65W x(;~$DWj,J auRs^b S*H-Y]FV T~PS*F8} OA<<qt n]`wK:ED }^B)]! kD[&y uwb_1nY&(F 7_K"c\T 7G0](BA3 ?UpyrP"Y5) @rTKasu`J uk,HFb^{ }IE|N L>$lwGtd dfQ;[.O}zY S`y/$ <\pzJ2\( S+g0IZ /9QKZ29BC jy3b%0KZb~ Eb"192nt Q8^[| <EZ'oN K8~uLh>Z?N KF*8,s3u C<4lxn%> sFARC r_s?Q~,)9y W)q=oQK]cK ?n^k}qwECZ I#@9CF "T1w@ &j(QfUio :O"m~{ <\&rxFVI !k9(Eq} Ezhc_="""
Правильный ответ с сайта 159 у меня 160

st = """"&p!2g Nz"E{ 0=cfc;*^{U bPf<:n/ 1>?j!#+|Ww kQsGs}] }48%s W?Kk4RdIK+ WCtv~_ t_.q4-! #%~=K /[r/,t#Se 1:fyl: KZx,o9 2*W[hp>X0" L0u0oFBY @"wHc bgRTj ,~OXJWt.Z jY*k2S:L x/jF>_#QRX Va(A/3 {4f32ZC|s 'f1MsZRK s+y@i lU<keS4! c!sA&i| rS'+-oNOj ']OzY?e# NDU!Sd) k5z#!n<4 p]kD,X5 c}aY|1"J ^KF}4sl ailA6Uw>$8 W{aA5ON~} 2}<C"p T&+h?\Y {Y9E$;4/.k GDYYXcK` ][h!l>*o!` &0?ST%v @+9T'-0F5U {Wh&ye:7 9CF0"n3 Nw/,L=+qK :jTZ;b,. wb=i_d5F i:(WF1 e;>9`#ToF ~z~-/ <uN], jc0[p$f3I r9M;Vm|%p 0)0<PS< CUtg2Gl@$ nnL]'O?N>C O9`YU 730|Y K!Sx,JL""""
```

Ответ с сервера 134 - у меня 135 - и так по всем рандомным тестам

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём причина? Как будто что-то (а что, не пойму) забываю удалить.

Comment: не только "and" и "And" разные слова, но и "and" и "aNd" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переведите все в одинаковый (например, нижний) регистр и потом сравнивайте.

```
import re

except_word = {"a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in", "as",
               "A", "The", "On", "At", "Of", "Upon", "In", "As", ""
               }
except_word = set(x.lower() for x in except_word) # здесь

def word_count(s):
    all_word = re.sub(r'([^A-Za-z]+)', r' ', s).split()
    cnt = 0
    for word in all_word:
        if word.lower() in except_word: # и здесь
            continue
        else:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = """R;!GV9sZrD 5x=jncajkU Z#0qd' rR"8oeAy:; IO$"EhYI), NG("Cy28 +ix>i kq&rV/ ',Sl[PL~ Ae/[< \-T<:/ D-$W9p5,Qh yF)DFS XFR@x{8[. L+(]M-cW J+i~E =g5B"1rGoM @c*ByGCt _2amHl =Y8f*E) P_F}01o t}1q!+A@| B3"S;; dP..'U >FqS>4D(S %rf/# =jB$+F<M G$:|K"rJn m92Fkv I^xuZ )s@~R65W x(;~$DWj,J auRs^b S*H-Y]FV T~PS*F8} OA<<qt n]`wK:ED }^B)]! kD[&y uwb_1nY&(F 7_K"c\T 7G0](BA3 ?UpyrP"Y5) @rTKasu`J uk,HFb^{ }IE|N L>$lwGtd dfQ;[.O}zY S`y/$ <\pzJ2\( S+g0IZ /9QKZ29BC jy3b%0KZb~ Eb"192nt Q8^[| <EZ'oN K8~uLh>Z?N KF*8,s3u C<4lxn%> sFARC r_s?Q~,)9y W)q=oQK]cK ?n^k}qwECZ I#@9CF "T1w@ &j(QfUio :O"m~{ <\&rxFVI !k9(Eq} Ezhc_="""

    print(word_count(st))

    st = """"&p!2g Nz"E{ 0=cfc;*^{U bPf<:n/ 1>?j!#+|Ww kQsGs}] }48%s W?Kk4RdIK+ WCtv~_ t_.q4-! #%~=K /[r/,t#Se 1:fyl: KZx,o9 2*W[hp>X0" L0u0oFBY @"wHc bgRTj ,~OXJWt.Z jY*k2S:L x/jF>_#QRX Va(A/3 {4f32ZC|s 'f1MsZRK s+y@i lU<keS4! c!sA&i| rS'+-oNOj ']OzY?e# NDU!Sd) k5z#!n<4 p]kD,X5 c}aY|1"J ^KF}4sl ailA6Uw>$8 W{aA5ON~} 2}<C"p T&+h?\Y {Y9E$;4/.k GDYYXcK` ][h!l>*o!` &0?ST%v @+9T'-0F5U {Wh&ye:7 9CF0"n3 Nw/,L=+qK :jTZ;b,. wb=i_d5F i:(WF1 e;>9`#ToF ~z~-/ <uN], jc0[p$f3I r9M;Vm|%p 0)0<PS< CUtg2Gl@$ nnL]'O?N>C O9`YU 730|Y K!Sx,JL"""

    print(word_count(st))
```

```
159
134
```

Comment: Только надо "A", "The", "On", "At", "Of", "Upon", "In", "As" убрать из множества.

Comment: @Эникейщик они сами уберутся после перевода в единый регистр. Проще, конечно, сразу задать множество в едином регистре.

Comment: "они сами уберутся" это то же самое, что "выливаем воду из чайника и сводим задачу к предыдущей" из анекдота :)

Comment: Просто я не понял задания(перевод плохой - считал что убрать только не нужные символы, а то что они могут быть в разных регистрах - об этом как бы в задании и не упоминалось) все что вы подсказали except_word = {"a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in", "as",
               "A", "The", "On", "At", "Of", "Upon", "In", "As", ""
               }
except_word = set(x.lower() for x in except_word)  нужно было просто как в начальном варианте даже использовать список  except_word = ["a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in", "as", ""] добавив пустую строку ещё === смотри далее

Comment: Самое главное что вы подсказали это то что нужно в цикле делать проверку - приводить слова к (одному какому-то) регистру и сравнивать с запрещёнными которые будут в том же регистре.И множество тут не нужно, запрещённых слов всего 8 - но с множеством тоже хорошо когда большие объёмы - да и скорость быстрая.Тесты прошли удачно! ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!!!!Нажму на "галочку".ВОПРОС ПОЛНОСТЬЮ ЗАКРЫТ!!!!